# Java @Component class and @Configuration class with AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I know springs `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` is capable of accepting not only `@Configuration` classes as input but also plain `@Component` classes and classes annotated with JSR-330 metadata.

I have created AppConfig.java below without @Configuration annotation.

```
public class AppConfig {

   @Bean(name="sampleService")
   public SampleService getSampleService(){
       return new SampleService();
   }

}
```

Passed this class as my java config class to `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`, it accepted and registered my service beans.

I did some modification on above same AppConfig like below.

```
  @Component
  public class AppConfig {

     @Bean(name="sampleService")
     public SampleService getSampleService(){
          return new SampleService();
     }
  }
```

passed AppConfig to AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, it accepted and registered my service beans.

Question:

1. `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` class is accepting the java config class with `@Configuration`, without `@Configuration` and with @Component annotations, what is the difference between `@Component` and `@Configuration`?
2. Why is it Accepting even without `@Configuration` annotation?
3. When to use `@Configuration`, and when to use @Component as java config class?

Answer (score 2):

[`@Component`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)

> Indicates that an annotated class is a "component".

That is, in a context where component scanning is enabled, Spring generates bean definitions for `@Component` annotated types. These bean definitions end up being turned into beans.

[`@Configuration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html), which is itself annotated with

> Indicates that a class declares one or more `@Bean` methods and may be
>   processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and
>   service requests for those beans at runtime, [...]

So any `@Configuration` type, for which Spring generates a bean, acts as a factory for beans.

The [javadoc of `@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) states

> `@Bean` methods may also be declared within classes that are not
>   annotated with `@Configuration`. For example, bean methods may be
>   declared in a `@Component` class or even in a plain old class. In such
>   cases, a `@Bean` method will get processed in a so-called 'lite' mode.
>
> Bean methods in lite mode will be treated as plain factory methods by
>   the container (similar to factory-method declarations in XML), with
>   scoping and lifecycle callbacks properly applied. The containing class
>   remains unmodified in this case, and there are no unusual constraints
>   for the containing class or the factory methods.
>
> In contrast to the semantics for bean methods in `@Configuration`
>   classes, 'inter-bean references' are not supported in lite mode.
>   Instead, when one `@Bean`-method invokes another `@Bean`-method in lite
>   mode, the invocation is a standard Java method invocation; Spring does
>   not intercept the invocation via a CGLIB proxy. This is analogous to
>   inter-`@Transactional` method calls where in proxy mode, Spring does not
>   intercept the invocation — Spring does so only in AspectJ mode.

So `@Bean` methods have full functionality in `@Configuration` annotated classes and limited functionality in `@Component` annotated classes.

> why it is Accepting even without @Configuration annotation?

That's how the class is designed. An `ApplicationContext` is a `BeanFactory`. `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` simply offers an extra way to register a bean definition.

> When to use @Configuration, and when to use @Component as java config class?

These really completely separate goals. Follow the javadoc. When you need to setup an `ApplicationContext`, you can use an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` with a `@Configuration` annotated class. If you simply need a bean, annotate its type with `@Component`.

Answer (score 0):

@Component annotation marks the **Java class as a bean**, but @Configuration annotation marks the **Java class containing beans (methods that have @Bean annotation)**.

> The **@Bean annotation must use with @Configuration exactly** to create Spring
>   beans.

In following class

```
  @Component
  public class AppConfig {

     @Bean(name="sampleService")
     public SampleService getSampleService(){
          return new SampleService();
     }
  }
```

@Bean annotation is not any effect, and getSampleService() method will be plain old java method and will not be **singleton**, because as i mentioned, **@Bean annotation must use with @Configuration**, so it must be repaired as following:

```
  @Configuration
  public class AppConfig {

     @Bean(name="sampleService")
     public SampleService getSampleService(){
          return new SampleService();
     }
  }
```

so replacing @Configuration annotation with any other annotation, or removing it, just make @Bean annotation **ineffective** and getSampleService() method will not be **singleton** anymore.