# Spring application having AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: getting run time exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

This is a continuation to [one of my SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409650/about-annotationconfigapplicationcontext-in-spring-framework).

I extended the same example and I expected it to work, however I am getting NullPointerException.

Here is the complete source code:

**FirstBean.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class FirstBean {

    public FirstBean() {

    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FirstBean [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

**SomeBean.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example" })
public class SomeBean {

    @Autowired
    private FirstBean fb;

    @Bean
    FirstBean instantiateFirstBean() {
        return new FirstBean();
    }

    public SomeBean() {
        // this.fb.setName("Some Name"); -> this was causing problem as 
        // bean isn't still created fully
    }

    public void print() {
        this.fb.toString(); 
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    void post() {
        fb.setName("Some name");
    }
}
```

**MainDriver.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example" })
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:/application.props")
public class MainDriver {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment cenv;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Autowired
    private SomeBean sb;

    @Bean
    public SomeBean instantiateSomeBean() {
        return new SomeBean();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MainDriver.class);

        MainDriver l = ctx.getBean(MainDriver.class);
        System.out.println("In main() the ctx is " + ctx);
        l.test();
    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("hello");
        sb.print();
    }
}
```

I was expecting `SomeBean` to get `Autowired` (`ctx`, `env`, `cenv` are getting Autowired perfectly),  but it is not getting and I am getting run time exception.

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainDriver': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sb'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'someBean' defined in file [/Users/vkoul/understand-code/platform/stream-base/trunk/target/classes/com/example/SomeBean.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.SomeBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fad3571b]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainDriver': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sb'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'someBean' defined in file [/Users/vkoul/understand-code/platform/stream-base/trunk/target/classes/com/example/SomeBean.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.SomeBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fad3571b]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
    at com.example.MainDriver.main(MainDriver.java:37)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'someBean' defined in file [/Users/vkoul/understand-code/platform/stream-base/trunk/target/classes/com/example/SomeBean.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.SomeBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fad3571b]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.SomeBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fad3571b]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:182)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.SomeBean.<init>(SomeBean.java:23)
    at com.example.SomeBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fad3571b.<init>(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170)
    ... 27 more
```

I am mentioning `@Bean` as well which I hoped it will tell how to create those beans, but still getting the exception.

What am I not understanding, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because Spring will first have to instantiate your `SomeBean` class and then it will try to autowire `FirstBean` through reflection because you put `@Autowired` annotation on the field.

You are trying to access `FirstBean` dependency in `SomeBean` constructor but when constructor of `SomeBean` is invoked, when context is being created, the `FirstBean` dependency is null because Spring has not autowired the dependency yet - it will try to autowire it through reflection after object creation. That is why you are getting `NullPointerException` there. The same situation happens with your `SomeBean` class - decide on one approach.

Additionaly it is strange that you create classes that are both annotated with `@Configuration` and `@Component`. Please refere to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183635/java-component-class-and-configuration-class-with-annotationconfigapplicationc) to see potential errors.

Moreover there are some issues in your configuration. You annotate `FirstBean` with `@Component` annotation and you still create a `@Bean` annotated method that returns instance of this class. You should decide on one apprach - you instantiate it for application context using `@Bean` annotation or you annotate this class with `@Component` and you let component scan automatically create it for you.

**EDIT** :

You should decide if you want to use `@ComponentScan` or you want to create your beans for context through `@Bean` annotation - right now you are mixing different types and you will get errors for duplicate bean definitions when trying to autowire by type, because in your current implementation there will be 2 bean for `SomeBean` and 2 beans for `FirstBean` in your context - they will only have different ids. Note that error that I pointed out with NPE expection has nothing to do with it. I will propose a solution using automated package scanning :

**FirstBean class**

```
@Component
public class FirstBean {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FirstBean [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

**SomeBean class**

```
@Component
public class SomeBean {

    private FirstBean fb;

    @Autowired
    public SomeBean(FirstBean firstBean) {
        this.fb = firstBean;
        this.fb.setName("Some Name");
    }

    public void print() {
        this.fb.toString();
    }
}
```

**MyConfig class**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example" })
public class MyConfig {

}
```

**MainDriver class**

```
@Component
public class MainDriver {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    protected ConfigurableEnvironment cenv;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Autowired
    private SomeBean sb;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);

        MainDriver l = ctx.getBean(MainDriver.class);
        System.out.println("In main() the ctx is " + ctx);
        l.test();
    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("hello");
        sb.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using `@component` so that is is picked up during component scan , and since it has `@Bean`, hence it needs to be annotated with `@Configuration` (which tells spring that it will give bean definitions, if my understanding is correct).   How can i fix it?

Comment: There are various problems with your approach, see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe the issue was I was trying to initializse the name in constructor of SomeBean() (and it may not have initialised properly); I added `@postConstruct` where I am setting the name.  It is not working fine now.

Comment: One small follow-up: I was under the impression that if there is `@Autowired` annotation , then that dependency is injected first before the current bean is created. Is this not correct?

Comment: Spring context is smart and when it sees that it has to create Bean for context and class for this bean has constructor annotated with `@Autowired` it will make sure to create dependencies-beans earlier and inject through constructor.